# How to arrive at a formula closed for a series, from the formula of partial sums.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a closed formula which determines the sum of a sequence
$$S_k = \frac{k - 1}{k + 1}$$
and from that closed formula I have to arrive at a formula for the$$ a_n$$I tried and got the following results 
$$ a_n= \frac{1}{a_{n-1}+3}$$ $$a_1 = \frac{1}{3}; n > 1$$
But I do not want this formula in the series to be definin by recurrence, is there another way to define the formula in this series?

Comment: So $S_k = \sum_{n=0}^k a_n$? Then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = \lim_{k\to \infty} S_k $.

Comment: Yes, but I need the closed formula of $ a_n $

Comment: ...then can you evaluate that limit?

Comment: Hint: $a_k=S_k-S_{k-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $S_k = \sum_{n=0}^k a_n$ we get

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = \lim_{k\to \infty} S_k = \lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{k-1}{k+1} = \lim_{k\to \infty} 1 - \frac{2}{k+1} = 1$$

If you want to find the closed form for $a_n$ then note that

$$a_n = S_{n}-S_{n-1} = \frac{n-1}{n+1} - \frac{(n-1)-1}{(n-1)+1}$$